# Gaps between drywall and door casing

Tags: drywall, doors, trim

I'm trying to paint my garage and noticed some gaps between the door casing and the drywall. Is there a way I can fill these so they appear flat?

Thinking of using some spray foam insulation for the larger gaps then shaving the excess down, and caulk for the smapler ones, not sure if this is the best approach.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the areas where the drywall paste (plaster) damp at all? Is the damage from something brushing or hitting the spots or does the wallboard move or flex?

Comment: Just bought the house so I'm not sure what the damage could have been from, but it's not wet and doesn't move. My best guess is they cut the drywall too wide before installing the door.

Comment: That looks like a "self-trimming" style door but it looks to be set in too far or the drywall is shimmed too far out from the studs for some reason.  Generally that border fits over the drywall and you get a nice clean finish without having to add trim.  You could add some trim around the outside to finish it at this point since I suspect you don't want to reinstall the door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no flex and not moisture damage, the classic method of repair is:

Find a drywall paste and use fiberglass-net type tape to reinforce it, directions are on the label. Use a 6” or 8” trowel and build up in layers after each one dries. Prime before painting.

Fill large cracks with foam or butyl tape/strips/rope first, then cover with layers of drywall paste as above. You can embed the net tape to reinforce the repaire in the first layer.

If the cracks are around a door that moves or flexes the wall, use just the weatherstripping or cover with flexible caulk. Make sure it’s labeled paintable if you want to paint it.

Comment: I’d remove any loose material, but it looks like a repair will work well.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll try the foam and drywall paste approach tonight.